# Increasing Google Apps Script MailApp email limit for personal account

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-workspace

Right now I'm hitting the 100 email a day limit on Apps Script, so I'm thinking of upgrading to a paid G-suite account to increase the limit to 1500. However, G Suite requires me to create a business account as part of that setup. Will I be able to access the 1500 email limit from my personal account (i.e., so the emails come from my personal account and not the business one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have 1,500* / day of Email recipients per day you need to upgrade at least to G Suite Basic.

Check out this art: [Current quotas][1]

Compare G Suite Editions: https://gsuite.google.com/compare-editions/

However As you stated you want to still use Apps Script with the personal account and obviously this limits won't apply. You would need to use the new G Suite account.

Having said that, creating a G suite Basic account it doesn't necessarily need to be a 'Business account' but it can be a 'personal account.' You would need to buy a domain name and create a new email address with the new domain name, for instance: myuser@mydomain.com.

However Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer users (You can do a manual payment of 30 $).
[1]: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Regarding your question 'Will I be able to access the 1500 email limit from my personal account' and 'Is there a way then to increase the limit for the personal account?'

You can't, the only solution is to go for a G Suite account.

Comment: Thanks, this was the detailed answer that I needed!

Answer (score 1):

No, the respective limits will continue to apply to both personal and business accounts.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way then to increase the limit for the personal account?